# Unexpected result on html5 canvas arcTo

Tags: html, canvas

I want to draw two lines that go through three points, and make a rounded corner at the second point. Here I have a problem. If the angle between the two lines is less than 90 degrees, there will be an extra line appended on the line through point1 and point2. If the angle is larger than or equal to 90 degrees, it will be ok, though.

You can see this in the snippet below:

```js
function Point(x, y){
  this.x = x ? x : 0;
  this.y = y ? y : 0;
}
var ctx,
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;

ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 2;

draw(ctx, new Point(50,10), new Point(20, 300), new Point(100, 320) );
draw(ctx, new Point(200,10), new Point(200, 300), new Point(300, 20) );

function draw(ctx, p1, p2, p3){
  var k1,k2, k, len, r=8;
  k1 = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
  k2 = Math.atan2(p3.y - p2.y, p3.x - p2.x);
  k = (k1-k2)/2;
  len = Math.abs(r/Math.tan(k));  // the distance between point of tangency and p2
  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p2.x - len*Math.cos(k1), p2.y - len*Math.sin(k1) ); // lineTo the point of tangency
  ctx.arcTo(p2.x, p2.y, p2.x + len*Math.cos(k2), p2.y + len*Math.sin(k2), r ); // then arc
  ctx.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y); // till p3
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' style="width:600px; height:600px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: yellow; "; />
```

Comment: You properly stop your line at `len` distance away from P2, but then you attempt to draw your `arcTo` directly to `p2.x,p2.y`. You should instead be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find your error so started again see http://jsfiddle.net/yUkK3/6/

Seems to work OK unless you have P1 and P3 in wrong order. (Last example on the fiddle) Can see why it happens but have not worked on correction yet.

Explanation of when it goes wrong.

Taking P2 as origin, rotate P1 so that P1 to P2 lies along x axis with P1 positive, then drawing fails when P3.y is negative.

Hope this helps

EDIT Have now sorted out the order problem described above.  http://jsfiddle.net/yUkK3/7/

Comment: Thank you very much, I find out my problem, it is because Math.atan2, it will return a negative angle when the angle is large than 90 degree, so it will effect my included angle 'k', so I modify it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/qiu8310/8cFZG/6/

Answer (score 0):

`Math.atan2` will return a negative angle when the angle is large than 90 degrees, which has the wrong effect on the angle `k`. To fix this, add the following code after `k1` and `k2` are calculated:

```
kk1 = k1<0 ? k1+Math.PI : k1;
kk2 = k2<0 ? k2+Math.PI : k2;
k = (kk1-kk2)/2;
```

Here is the full working code:

```js
function Point(x, y){
  this.x = x ? x : 0;
  this.y = y ? y : 0;
}

var ctx,
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = 600;
canvas.height = 600;

ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 2;

draw(ctx, new Point(50,10), new Point(20, 300), new Point(100, 320) );
draw(ctx, new Point(200,10), new Point(200, 300), new Point(300, 20) );

function draw(ctx, p1, p2, p3){
  var k1,k2, k, len, r=8, kk1,kk2;

  k1 = Math.atan2(p2.y - p1.y, p2.x - p1.x);
  k2 = Math.atan2(p3.y - p2.y, p3.x - p2.x);
  kk1 = k1<0 ? k1+Math.PI : k1;
  kk2 = k2<0 ? k2+Math.PI : k2;
  k = (kk1-kk2)/2;
  len = Math.abs(r/Math.tan(k));  // the distance between point of tangency and p2

  ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
  ctx.lineTo(p2.x - len*Math.cos(k1), p2.y - len*Math.sin(k1) ); // lineTo the point of tangency
  ctx.arcTo(p2.x, p2.y, p2.x + len*Math.cos(k2), p2.y + len*Math.sin(k2), r ); // then arc
  ctx.lineTo(p3.x, p3.y); // till p3
  ctx.stroke();
}
```

```html
<canvas id='canvas' style="width:600px; height:600px; margin: 0 auto; background-color: yellow; "; />
```